# What prometheus metric can be used to see the contents of the request?

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, metrics

I would like to count the number of requests made to my application from one of the client. The client string is present in http REST request. I want to use prometheus. Is there any metric provided by prometheus that i can use to filter out the content of the request by reading the client or do I need to define custom metric ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It depends but probably (!?) not.

There are various ways (e.g. [HTTP](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/#http); [Go client SDK](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/go-application/)) that your server may be instrumented (to emit metrics that may be scraped) by Prometheus.

You will need to review the list of exported metrics and, most importantly the [labels](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/#labels) that are captured for the metric. In your case, you'd want something like the [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)(?) request header to be captured as a label.

It's probable (I don't know) that the User-Agent is **not** being captured because there are (a) [many](https://deviceatlas.com/blog/list-of-user-agent-strings) possible values for User-Agent; (b) the User-Agent value is a composite value.

Generally (!) Prometheus metric label values should take a limited set of values because each value is stored as a distinct time series in Prometheus (increasing storage).

If you write your own exporter, then you may capture whatever metrics and labels you wish (although be aware of the above proviso).

Observability covers logs, metrics and traces. Conventionally (!?) logs would be used to capture some subset of (a possibly sampled subset of) request headers.